# Прокрутка на jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть код прокрутки до нужного id.
Как сделать, чтобы прокручивалось выше на 60 пикселей до id?

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

        // = Вешаем событие прокрутки к нужному месту
        //   на все ссылки якорь которых начинается на #
        $('a[href^="/#"]').bind('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
            var target = this.hash
            $target = $(target);
            if ($target.size()<=0) {
                return 
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
            }, 900, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;

            });
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Написал свою функцию:

```
var elem = $(*Тут Элемент*).offset().top;  
var top = elem - 60;    
$('html, body').animate({  
scrollTop: top  
}, 2000);
```